# google map with gps tracking

Tags: google-maps

i want to put marker on the only visited path not on any point to the map... my code like this

```
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            zoom: 15,
                    center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addNewPoint)

  }

$(document).ready(function(){

initialize();
temp();

});


function reload()
{
window.location.href='<?=base_url()?>index.php/admin/tracking';
}


function addNewPoint(e)
{

 var data="";

 if(i>0)
{
      for (i in markersArray)
      {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      }
            markersArray.length = 0;
}
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/admin/tracking/get_last_location',
       // data: 'season_id='+season_id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
               var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(msg.lat,msg.lng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: e.latLng});
        data+="Position :-"+e.latLng;
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': e.latLng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[1]) {
      map.setZoom(13);
      infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
      data+="\naddress :-"+results[1].formatted_address;

      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    document.getElementById('info').value=data;

  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
        });
  }
});

 markersArray.push(marker);

 i++;

 }


function temp1(){

$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/admin/tracking/get_last_location',
       // data: 'season_id='+season_id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
               var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(msg.lat,msg.lng);
                map.panTo(newLatlng);
                document.getElementById('speed').value=msg.speed;
                if(myPoints.length>0)
                {
                   var oldLatlng=myPoints[myPoints.length-1];
                    var myCoordinates = [
                            oldLatlng,
                            newLatlng
                          ];
                          if(oldLatlng!=newLatlng)
                          {
                              var myPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                path: myCoordinates,
                                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                strokeWeight: 2
                              });
                              way.push(myPath);
                              myPath.setMap(map);
                          }
                          myPoints.push(newLatlng);



                }
                else
                {
                //var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value['lat'],value['long']);
                    myPoints.push(newLatlng);


                }

        }

    });
    setTimeout("temp1()",2000);

   }

  function deleteOverlays() {
 if (myPoints.length>0) {
  for (i in myPoints) {
  myPoints[i].setMap(null);
 }
 myPoints.length = 0;
 }
 if (way.length>0) {
  for (i in way) {
  way[i].setMap(null);
 }
 way.length = 0;
}

}
```

but from this code i can only put marker at one point. what can i do???

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a shot at helping although it's been years since I worked with Google maps.

The code to push the new marker into the array is outside of the success function where the new marker is created. Plus, if you have initialized the array with values, I suspect that pushing a new value adds it to the array after all of the data that you already initialized.

But I am not at all sure why this would give you any marker at all.

I suggest leaving the array uninitialized and then pushing the new marker inside of the AJAX success function. Set the map for the marker and any other information there using the new marker object to make things very clear.

I am not 100% sure about the array push issue of appending to an array that already has values but I hope this information helps you find a solution.